# How much Linux Kernel Source code for Pc env can be used for BSP

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

I am just going through Linux kernel source code for PC environment and wanted to know how much Linux Kernel Source code for Pc env can be used for writing BSP code for specific platform ,say I wanted to write BSP for x86 underlaying architecture to up pci bus and some hardware register.

Would linux kernel source be any helpful in this scenario?

Comment: please clarify your question. If you're using x86, then you probably won't need to develop any part specific for the architecture, but you may only need to develop a driver if you need to support a custom pci board.

Comment: I would be ineterested bsp for Embedded board where Embedded linux would running and U-boot is my bootloader.

Comment: Well, if you want to make a BSP for an x86 board you're going to reuse 100% of the linux kernel sources, because you don't need to port anything at all. Probably, you'll just change the bootloader to use u-boot.

Comment: "BSP" while having some meaning seems to be a buzzword heavily misused by those handed their first embedded assignment.  It would be better to focus on the specific things which are missing but needed.